# Why does (#(+ % 1) 3) work but (#(%) 3) not work in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Title says it all. Why does `(#(+ % 1) 3)` work but `(#(%) 3)` not work in Clojure? instead, it gives an error:

```
1. Unhandled java.lang.ClassCastException
   java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Shouldn't `#(%)` be the same as the `identity` function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. `#(%)` is attempting to call %. It's the same as `(fn [x] (x))`. In your specific case, you're attempting to call 3 as a function.

An identity function would be `#(do %)` because `do` evaluates the expressions following it and returns the last one.

Comment: But why does `%` mean the argument value in the first example but calling the argument in the second example?

Comment: Because it's the first thing after `(` in the second example. The first thing after `(` is the function you're calling. In the first example it's the `+`.

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks.